# GridView ASP if the table is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I display a message in the place of the GridView if there is no results come from the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `GridView` has an `EmptyDataRow` template and style, just make the use of that:

```
  <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    runat="server">

    <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      forecolor="Red"/>

    <emptydatatemplate>

      <asp:image id="NoDataImage"
        imageurl="~/images/Image.jpg"
        alternatetext="No Image" 
        runat="server"/>

        No Data Found.  

    </emptydatatemplate> 

  </asp:gridview>
```

example from MSDN [`GridView.EmptyDataRowStyle` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatarowstyle.aspx) (available since .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 4):

There is also the `EmptyDataText` property that you type on the `<asp:GridView ... >`

`EmptyDataText="There is no items in the list box"`

and the `EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass` to style it.

Comment: This only provides a way to show a label alike control, while `emptydatatemplate` gives you the opportunity of be a little more creative :)

Comment: I'm way behind this... been in MVC since they started, and no more `GridView`s ;)

Comment: @balexandre I am not on MVC at all... :( how you handle there a GridView like list ?

Comment: I agree with you. How ever I use this one on all of my grid views, except one. When I do not have data to show, I prefer to not draw the attention. It also one more way to show that there is no data :

Comment: In MVC you stop using those controls that gives you no handling  of the output code, you kind'a go back to the old ASP Classic way, here is an [example using Razor View](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5) on [ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/mvc). Remember that in ASP.NET website you have a nice course for MVC, WebForms and WebPages for free :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[EmptyDataText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext.aspx)** property.

```
GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No data found";
```

Other way, but the one given above is better approach.

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    lblAfterGridGridView1.TextEmptyDataText = "No recorddata found";
}
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //Show grid here
    lblAfterGrid.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: +1 You might want to set the `lbl.Visible = true;` when there are no results and false when there are.

Comment: kind'a stupid to create a new label and a new condition check when `GridView` object provides such thing no?

Comment: You are welcome @Fady, I have updated my answer with better way.

Comment: @balexandre this property in introduce in framework 2.0 and wont work on 1.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.emptydatatemplate(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Adil and since when the person who asked this question mention anything with a framework version? That you should ask him as a comment... but if you would know `<asp:gridview>` you would know that it's a web control only available [since .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx)

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong but telling you this property is not available in older version and using label will work for that.

Comment: and I will keep telling you, `<asp:GridView>` **is .NET 2.0**, and you would never use 2 `if` statements, at least you would just use one line of code `lblAfterGrid.Visibility = dt != null && dt.Rows.Count == 0;` and that will do the trick... so much code for such simple task.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put right into your code behind:
C#

```
GridView1.EmptyDataText = "This table has no data, or whatever";
```

This approach is nice because you can control when to display which message.

I.E. in my case, when the page first appears (!IsPostback) I can say: "Please select the fields..."

and if the query comes up empty, then I can say: "Sorry, no data found...."

Answer (score 0):

use `EmptyDataText` property to set your Empty Grid text. and Just bind your `DataGrid` with null, to show up Empty Text..

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  //call Bind grid method here       
}
else
{
     Grid.DataSource=null;
     Grid.DataBind();
}
```